# Непонятные названия класс css на многих сайтах

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, классы, sass

Стал замечать на сайтах интересные названия для классов. Все они начинаются на css- и заканчиваются каким-то наборов цифр и букв. Вот, например:
css-79txt3, css-159p4b7, css-1s44ra и кучу разных других примеров. Интересно: им же не просто так задают название? Может они чему-то соответствуют? Ну, например, как на bootstrap: mr-1 - внешний отступ справа на одну единицу и т.п. Может кто знает? 
Буду очень рад, невероятно интересно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Таким образом мудаки-сайтовладельцы борются с блокировщиками рекламы. Нормальный человек, если видит, что его АдБлок не удалил рекламную какашку, лезет в ручное блокирование, инспектит элемент и блочит по его css-классу. А нехорошие веб-мастера наловчились генерировать классы на лету, чтобы каждый раз они были разными, а блокировка оптом по шаблону затрагивала и контент тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Классы вроде `css-79txt3` элементам задают не люди, а какая-то технология/программа, при помощи которой разработан сайт. Это имя и имеет значение только для этой программы/технологии при построении сайта.